# Why does my HTML code get hidden on server but its fine on the local machine?

Tags: html, css, openshift

I have a section in the code which displays three hyperlinks through the use of the  tag. When I open the HTML file locally on the laptop, they show just fine and work.

However, when I use the live server extension on VS code, they appear to be hidden when I inspect element, this also applies when I deploy the website on Openshift. I'm not sure why it does that.

```css
.social_media a {
 width: 33.3%;
 font-size: xx-large;
}

.social_media a:hover {
 background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<section class="middle_bottom">

    <section>
     <h1>Social Media</h1>
    </section>

    <div class="social_media">
     <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">
      Linkedin
     </a>
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
      Facebook
     </a>
     <a href="https://www.instagram.com">
      Instagram
     </a>
    </div>

</section>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is, Everything else works otherwise.

Comment: I realise that.I'm not sure why this gets added since I didn't add it into the source code.

Comment: On other pages on my website, I did use Javascript, but for this specific page, it is purely made of HTML and CSS.

Comment: look like you have some more css in your screenshot, no problem there? What does F12 say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was only specific for Opera Browser for some reason while it worked perfectly on other browsers like chrome